# Android menu of toolbar response to different fragment

Tags: android, menu, fragment, toolbar

Now my mainActivity.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/tab_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_bar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This page has four tabs on the bottom,each tab is associated with a different fragment which will be added to android:id="@+id/tab_content".

The menu_main.xml like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_calendar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_title_date"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/calendar"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_notification"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_title_notification"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="@string/notification"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

I have these code in my MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Fragment2 and Fragment3 have these code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_calendar)
    {
        showDatePicker();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

android:id="@+id/action_calendar" menuItem is a datePicker,and i want to use this menuItem to be filter to load data for fragment2 and fragment3.

Here is my question,when I navigate to the fragment3 and click the calendar menu and then change to fragment2,click the calendar,the system call onOptionsItemSelected method in fragment 3 ,not in fragment2 ? 
I want calendar menu response to different fragment separately .

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include mainActivity.xml and make sure the formatting doesn't eat it. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: @NathanTuggy I will try to format the code again.

Comment: can you please post complete code of fragment 2 and fragment 3

Comment: try adding -- menu.clear(); inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu); -- in fragment onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: @Harry  Thanks your answer. I have added menu.clear() before, but failed.

Comment: @Keshav1234 I think other code of fragment2 and fragment 3 have nothing   to do with the question.They are just normal fragment with listView Layout.